# Given some set of alph-numeric strings generated from a function, is there a way to find the function?

Tags: functions, pattern-recognition

The function in this case is a poorly programmed number generator which generates a alpha-numeric string of X characters. Instead of random numbers, numeric constants have been used to generate the numbers.

Is there a tool or a method that I can use to find the function?